# grails sprint security page redirect to login page

Tags: spring-security, grails3

So I am able to successfully install plugin 3.1.2 to grails 3.1.
I want to show common general info page and then when the user clicks on the login option then redirect the user to /login/auth page. But right now as soon as I start my app it goes to /login/auth page?

Thanks,
Snehal

Answer (score 0):

In application.groovy file, you will see a code similar to this.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    [pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/error',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/index',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/index.gsp',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/shutdown',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/assets/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/js/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/css/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/images/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']]
```

This basically tells Spring Security what urls can any specific user can see. 'permitAll' means all users can access the url, even those who are not logged in.

After you have created the general page that you want users to see, add the rules in this file

```
[pattern: '/info', access: ['permitAll']]
```

Spring Security will now allow access to that page to not-logged in users.

Comment: so when I use " / "  permit al option : l its permitting /testsuite/inputpage too ..I want to permit  all users to "/testsuite/info" page but not to inputpage..I also have secured annotation in the controller and above method buts its not working